# Draw lines between ListView rows

Tags: android, listview, overriding

I have ListView with ImageView in rows.

I need to draw lines between these ImageViews.

So one line is started at first row at ImageView position and ends at second row at ImageView position. And so on.

What is the best way to draw these lines?

Thank you.

UPDATE. I am sorry, I can't upload image and I speak english not very well.

It is not horizontal divider between rows. If to simplify it: line starts at vertical center of one row at ImageView position and ends with vertical center of next row at ImageView position.

I think I should try:

1. To override row view.
   At Adapter's GetView where I create row view pass to this row view coordinates of adjacent rows.
   In view's onDraw method calculate coordinates and draw line.
2. To override ListView. In it's OnDraw method try to get ImageView's positions and draw all lines.

Answer (score 6):

```
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <ListView 
         android:id="@+id/android:list"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:divider="#FFCC00"
         android:dividerHeight="4px"/>

      </LinearLayout>
```

Have a listview seperator.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but this should make really nice gradient lines between rows :

```
    mListView = getListView();
    mAdapter = new ServersListAdapter(this, new String[] {},
            new String[] {}, new String[] {});
    int[] colors = { Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"), Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"), Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3") };
    mListView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a view you can draw a line in. Create this class, refresh your palette if you need to.

```java
public class LineTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public LineTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), paint);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in your `layout`

```xml
<LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.example.taskmodel.view.LineTextView
            android:id="@+id/lineTextViewTopHalf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <com.example.taskmodel.view.LineTextView
            android:id="@+id/lineTextViewBottomHalf"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```